# bootstrap is not included in yeoman fountain webapp

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, yeoman-generator-angular

I am having issue with bootstrap less to include in yeoman fountain webapp. I have installed the bootstrap inside yeoman folder with below command `bower install --save angular-bootstrap`. it's installed but when I use any component or CSS class from bootstrap showing a basic html element.
I have included into modules as like `angular
    .module('myModule', ['ui.router','ngSanitize','ui.bootstrap']);` and i have updated in `bower.json` as like below

```
 {
  "name": "appName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.6.4",
    "angular-ui-router": "~1.0.0-beta.3",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.6.4",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.6.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.6.4"
  },
  "overrides":{
    "bootstrap" : {
         "main": [
            "less/bootstrap.less",
            "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
          ]
    }
  }
}
```

The only way I found to add the stylesheet is to input `@import "../../bower_components/pathOftheFile"` in the index.scss file. But I think it is not a good practice to do it that way.Please anyone suggest a solution to add bootstrap into my code.

Thanks,

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: no error message but the bootstrap style is not included

Comment: In this case, you're doing good considering you are using bower

Comment: I got a solution `bootstrap` package name and path is different. I have changed the package as like below. `bootstrap: 3.3.4` . It works fine